# how to make possible that After a certain amount of time, the users should be signed off automatically?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, session-cookies

user should sign off automatically after few minute, like 20-30 minute? and get back to the  login page, even if they doing something on website, i'm using mvc5.

can IIS overwrite our web.config's session timeout changes ?

Comment: are you using identity server for your authentication?

Comment: How is your user session managed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Identity server provides you with everything you need to handle session length and a variety of other features to suit your needs. Take a look at the following guide that will get you started in understanding identity server.

The timeout of each user gets checked against the identity server security store and you can renew / revoke access tokens as needed.

[Getting started with identity server 4](https://www.scottbrady91.com/Identity-Server/Getting-Started-with-IdentityServer-4)